# WatiN cannot find an element by Regex

Tags: c#, regex, watin

I have a span on page with the text "Details for item 1 bla-bla-bla". This code works OK:

```
IE.Span(Find.ByText(new Regex("Details for item 1"))).Click();
```

But this ('I' in upper case) - element not found:

```
IE.Span(Find.ByText(new Regex("Details for Item 1"))).Click();
```

Why? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `(?i)` to make it case insensitive

```
new Regex("(?i)Details for Item 1 bla-bla-bla")
```